# Sencha Touch: Unable to Build Package: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency

Tags: build, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, package, sencha-architect

I have a Sencha Touch App and also a Sencha Touch Package with the following basic structure:

MyApp

```
 /app

 /packages/MyPackage
```

When I try to build the package by executing:

> sencha package build

(inside packages/MyPackage)

I get the following error:

> [ERR] Failed to resolve dependency Ext.data.writer.Writer for file Ext.ux.MyClass [ERR]  [ERR] BUILD FAILED [ERR]
>   com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency :
>   Ext.data.writer.Writer [ERR]  [ERR] Total time: 1 second [ERR] The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /MyApp/packages/MyPackage/.sencha/package/build-impl.xml:137: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /MyApp/packages/MyPackage/.sencha/package/js-impl.xml:32:
>   com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency :
>   Ext.data.writer.Writer

MyClass extends Ext.data.writer.Writer, in the following way:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.MyClass', {
extend: 'Ext.data.writer.Writer',
alias: 'writer.myclass',
```

I understand that during the compiling process the source of the class Ext.data.writer.Writer cannot be determined. How can I solve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Guys, I was able to build my package by editing the following config file:

> /MyApp/packages/MyPackage/.sencha/package/sencha.cfg

I added the touch framework to the package classpath.

**Before:**

> package.classpath=${package.dir}/src

**After**

> package.classpath=${package.dir}/src,${touch.dir}

Answer (score 1):

In your sencha.cfg you should set:

```
package.framework=touch
```

It will add the framework to the classpath